# MS Teams Graph API Webhook - How to subscribe chat message on MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In MS Teams Graph API Subscription, as per the [API Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage#subscribe-to-messages-in-a-chat), we can subscribe chat (1:1 or group chat) but that requires to provide the chat id.
There is an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#response) to get list of chat id but it is not yet supported for Application Permission.

Do we have any other alternative to subscribe chat without chat id?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got the answer: we can subscribe at all chats at tenant level as well using /chats/getAllMessages
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage#subscribe-to-messages-in-a-chat